# Mobile Safari Not allowing typing in Textarea when Jquery Focus event is triggered?

Tags: jquery, textbox, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I've been having an issue with textboxes in Mobile Safari. When this function is included:

```
$("#text_comment").live('focus', function () {
    $(this).css('height','50px');
});

$("#text_comment").live('focusout', function () {
    $(this).css('height','23px');
});
```

**The function resizes the textbox on focus, but you can no longer type in the textbox. On the iPhone you can click the letters on the keyboard but nothing shows up.**

I think it has to do with the event interfering with mobile safari's ability to insert characters into the textarea, but it is very annoying.

Does anyone have a fix, or can a second focus event be triggered to allow the text to show up?

Comment: I've tested the code above on my iPhone with a blank page with only a text area and it seems to be working perfectly fine. The only suggestion I have is that you should either use focus/blur or focusin/focusout to handle the events not a mixture of both.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I have found the error, it is an issue with the mobile safari that comes with iOS 4.2.1. Thank you for testing it. I wil post my solution below. And thank you, I will use focus/blur now.

Comment: I'm using iOS 5 (as I'm a developer) which could explain why it's working fine for me. Apple must have fixed that bug.

Comment: That is good to know, I will work with my function to reduce its impact on performance. As of right now there are no issues but I don't really like the idea of running a function on every keypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my solution to my own question:

```
$('#text_comment, searchinput, timestamp').live('keypress', function(event) {

      var txt = $('#spn').text();
      var pressed = (txt + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));

    var el = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
         var string = $(el).val(); 
         if(string.length < 1) {
            $(el).val(pressed);
         }
    }, 100);

});
```

It should work for anyone having this issue.